# External-API call caching in Django

Tags: python, django, caching, optimization, yql

I am developing a Django application for retrieving some information from YQL - in total - the homepage itself has about 5 requests,where 1 is real time and others are past data requests - and so it is taking a lot of time to load.
The responses from the API call are not stored in my database and are merely displayed.
I want to optimize the past-data fetch part by caching and thus would require some guidance regarding how to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not enough information. For example, is the data user-specific? Or is the the same for all users? How often does it need to update? Etc..

Comment: @rnevius  
So the data is a public one - not user specific. It is basically the live score of a cricket match,which is updated every 2 minutes , with the data of the past 3 matches also available. So once an ongoing match ends,it then becomes a part of the past 3 matches. Is there any further information you need?

Answer (score 6):

Well, in the first instance, your question is pretty poor because you haven't specified what you've tried.  BUt caching external calls you're going to be showing is a good idea.

The [Django docs have a very clea](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/)r explanation of how to set up caching. 
Once you've set that up (Db caching is easiest for localhosting, in my experience, memcached for anything approaching production):

Add to settings.py:

```
    CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'my_cache_table',
    }
}
```

Make sure you sync the db at this point if you're using the DatabaseCache option.

Now, if we assume you've got something like for your API call:

```
scraped_data = external_api_call()
```

Then you can just do:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache_key = "match1"
cache.set(cache_key, scraped_data, None)
```

I've broken this out into extra steps, and don't normally define the cache_key seperately!  That 'None' on the end sets it to never expire - you can set your own expiry, in seconds, in there.

If you're going to define your cache keys dynamically, then probably do something like this:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from django.core.cache import cache
cache_key = sha256(str(variable1)+str(variable2)) 
cache.set(cache_key, stuff_stored, None)
```

To get that information back from the cache, you simply do:

```
stuff_i_want = cache.get(cache_key)
```

Similarly, if you wanted to delete a cache item, it's just:

```
cache.delete(cache_key)
```